# How to order by months DESC

Tags: php, mysql

I have data stored in a month column in my database. It is stored like this:

January
February
March
April
May 
etc...

They are stored as varchar.

How can I order by the month using SQL? At the moment it is ordering incorrectly even though I have ORDER BY `month` in my SQL.

Comment: `"At the moment it is ordering incorrectly"` - How so?  I would expect string values to be ordered alphabetically.  Is it not doing that?

Comment: select * from 'table_name' order by month desc; What does it give you as a result?

Comment: It gives me March, January, February

Comment: I think you now see your database design error

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I don't actually know what is wrong.

Comment: There is no need to store a month specifically and definitely not as a string. A DATE or DATETIME or TIMESTAMP column should be used. There are various functions in MYSQL to get a DAY or MONTH or YEAR etc etc from a date column

Comment: @RiggsFolly, how the site works is that I am meant to select a month from a dropdown value for monthly reports to submit. So, for a particular month I need to submit for, what should the "value" be in the dropdown instead of using the literal name for the month?

Comment: I dont know enough about your system to take guesses like that

Comment: @RiggsFolly,  It's pretty simple. It just has JAN to DEC like this ' <option value="January">January</option>'. I would just need to know what to replace "January" with in this example.

Comment: Your question says that the months are stored as `January`.... so I assume `value="January"` would work in a query like  `WHERE month = ?` and bind `January`

Comment: @Jonathan: `"I don't actually know what is wrong."` - Technically *nothing* is wrong.  You have strings, and they are being sorted correctly.  The descending alphabetical order for the three you gave are M, J, and F.  That's how sorting works.  The problem is that you're not storing the data you want to store.  The sort works exactly the way it's supposed to.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I want to be able to store the data so that I can order it by Month in order of actual months of the year, not by the order of records in my database.

Comment: Again: Nowhere near enough information availaible to do this for you.

Comment: @Jonathan: Then store the months as numbers instead of words.  1-12 will sort the way you want it to.  Words will sort alphabetically.

Comment: @David, that's a good idea but I want it to display month names when I pull the data.

Comment: @Jonathan: You can translate to the names in the code.  Or create a look-up table of numbers/names and translate in the `SELECT` statement.  It's okay to hard-code something like this.  It's highly unlikely that months will change.  (Barring the need to support different languages, that is.)

Comment: @David, should I store as 1-12 or 01, 02, 03 etc?

Comment: @Jonathan: The difference between `1` and `01` is a matter of display formatting, it has nothing to do with the data itself.  You can format the display in your code, or perhaps in your `SELECT` if you want.  The database doesn't store formatting, it just stores numeric data as data.

Comment: @David, okay. I was just asking so that at a later stage if I need to use php date time functions I wasn't going to run into trouble because I used 1 instead of 01 or visa versa

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from your_table
order by case when month = 'January' then 1 
              when month = 'February' then 2
              ...
              when month = 'December' then 12
         end
```

Answer (score 0):

Mysql has a [field function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_field) that does pretty much this.

```
select field(month, 'january', 'february', 'march',
                    'april',   'may',      'june',
                    'july',    'august',   'september',
                    'october', 'november', 'december')
```

it will return the index of the first argument in the list that is the rest of the arguments or `0` if not found. So for this month (may), it would return `5`. You can order by this return value as well.